# Teamcity v7.0.2 - checkout directory file cannot be deleted when applying patch

Tags: c#, teamcity

One of developer is applying patch to CI and has broken the CI build. The error occurred as below in the build log. I have done the below steps and still doesnot work.

1. I could not delete the folder: 35b0f615bcea75bd  manually eventhough I have full write and delete access to the build agent directories.
2. I have tried to run Enforce clean checkout, still doesnot work.
3. Have re-run the build, still doesnot work.

Questions:

1. Is deleting this file manually the best solution to fix the below error?
2. If the answer is "yes", what should I try next to delete this file?
3. What is the best way to prevent this error to happen again when applying patch?

Build log:

```
[18:32:28]Checking for changes
[18:35:15]Publishing internal artifacts
[18:35:15]Clearing temporary directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\temp\buildTmp
[18:35:15]Checkout directory: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\35b0f615bcea75bd
[18:35:15]Updating sources: server side checkout (2m:09s)
[18:35:16][Updating sources] Will perform clean checkout. Reason: Agent doesn't have any version of the project sources
[18:35:16][Updating sources] Building clean patch for VCS root: ProjectName Trunk
[18:37:24][Updating sources] Transferring cached clean patch for VCS root: ProjectName Trunk
[18:37:25][Updating sources] Repository sources transferred: 27.61Mb total
[18:37:25][Updating sources] Removing D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\35b0f615bcea75bd
[18:37:25][Updating sources] Error while applying patch: Failed to delete: D:\TeamCity\buildAgent\work\35b0f615bcea75bd\ProjectName\bin\Debug
[18:37:25]Publishing internal artifacts
[18:37:25]Build failed to start. Artifacts will not be published for this build
[18:37:26]Build finished
```

Answer (score 11):

We have had this issue when running Selenium tests and the browser was not properly shut down. We actually created a powershell script that we execute as a build on any of our agents that will kill any outstanding IE or Firefox or Chrome processes. We also ensured that our tests always close the browser on teardown.

If you have enough privileges, you can remotely restart the build agent from the TeamCity web interface. You this by clicking on the Agents tab at the top, selecting the offending agent, and then select "Reboot Agent Machine". You can read more in the [TeamCity documentation](http://confluence.jetbrains.net/display/TCD7/Viewing+Build+Agent+Details).

Comment: We've had this - You don't need to reboot the machine actually, you can log into it, go to task manager and stop the processes chrome.exe and chromedriver.exe, that did the trick for us

Comment: I've just run into this exact scenario. Any chance you could post that PS script?

Comment: Get-Process chromedriver | kill

Answer (score 10):

Question 1. Yes, deleting the folder is your best bet to resolve the current situation.

Question 2. Whenever I've had an issue like this it's been because there is a file in use in the folder that cannot be deleted. So I would suggest that you use a tool like [Process Monitor](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) on the TeamCity server to work out what file is in use.

Question 3. Once you have worked out what was in use you'll need to work out why to stop it again.

Answer (score 3):

1.In my case it was the folder itself that was locked. TC gives error: [TEAMCITY TEMPLATE ERROR] and "Failed to create a directory; error message is logged."

2.Using the Unlocker tool, I was able to see and fix that 'system' had a lock on the folder. Possibly this was due to a Teamcity build not properly cleaning up after itself?

3.If so, it looks like I should try to use the [Swabra][1] plugin to ensure this will not recur.

[1] http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TCD6/Adding+Swabra+as+a+Build+Feature

Answer (score 2):

Just for the record :) Reboot the agent machine --> This reboots the machine (as written lol) and not only the agent :) ... and that solved my problem. The folder may have been locked by a process.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on the answer from @cezarypiatek:

If you don't have access to log into the machine, you could try adding a Powershell Build step that runs:

```
Get-Process chromedriver | kill
Get-Process chrome | kill
```

Ensure that the step is set to run even if the build fails.

You can then just disable this step, ready to be used next time this comes up.